# Is a const HANDLE really const?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, handle

As far is I learned a HANDLE is just a number referring to some kind of "sytem ressource table". Is this handle const correct? I guess not because it is just used to access a table like an index on an array. An example with bitmaps: Can I change the content of a bitmap althought the HBITMAP is declared const?

Comment: Does the API function take a `const HBITMAP` or just a `HBITMAP`? That should answer your question. If it's the latter then don't bother declaring it as `const` (you'll just end up casting away the constness anyway). Also, a `HANDLE` may not be just a number, it might be an opaque type pointer that points directly to some allocated resource, without any table translation in between. It's best not to make assumption about such opaque types.

Comment: A HANDLE always refers to the same operating system object.  Whose state may certainly mutate, like a bitmap or mutex.  So it is a `foo const*`, not a `const foo*`.

Answer (score 3):

HANDLE is (AFAIR) a typedef of int so const HBITMAP is the same as const int.

In this sense you can change the contents of the bitmap even if handle to the bitmap is const because const refers to the handle not the actual bitmap (think of it as a const pointer to a variable class.)

BUT:

Your question is moot anyway because:

- Handles are a feature of the Win32 API which is a C api not a C++ (and created before C gained const).
- You cannot change bitmaps (or any other "object" represented by a handle) directly anyway. The handle is an opaque reference to Win32 structures and can be manipulated only through the appropriate Win32 API calls used to handle (no pun intended) the "object".

I place "object" in quotes because Handles refer to conceptual objects (software representations of concepts) not actual C++ objects, again because Win32 is a C API.

Comment: Good call on the reference to an "object". When dealing with handles, it's best to think of them as black boxes with the functions that access them being the methods.

Comment: `HANDLE` is a `void*` (though it might have been some sort of `int` at some point of Window's history). Other handles (like HBITMAP) are pointers to some struct type if `STRICT` is defined; if `STRICT` is not defined, they're just a typedef for `HANDLE`.

Comment: @Michael thanks, I did not have an SDK handy at the moment. It would make sense to typedef them to void* as int is still 32 bit in 64 bit windows.

Comment: Since HANDLE is `struct HANDLE__ *` (where HANDLE__ is just `struct {int unused}`), `const HANDLE hFoo` resolves to `HANDLE__ *const` (const pointer to struct) and not `const HANDLE__ *` (pointer to const struct) as you might expect.